# Standard Practice for importing and replacing an existing Winforms design into new Winforms project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've got a winforms that looks like the following:

[image]

It has an associated code file behind the controls.
It is located in solution X. 
There are various other files in X.

I have created a new solution Y with a new blank winforms project in it. 
When this is created a load of boilerplate code is created that relates to the blank form. 
From X I'd like to import just the above design (with corresponding code) into this project to replace the existing blank form.

Is it easy to do this without confusing the existing project due to all the boilerplate code?

I've tried right-clicking the *project* in the Solution Expl and using `Add` > `Existing Item` but this just confuses the issue. Maybe this is a pointless exercise and I should just right-click the *solution* in the Solution Expl and using `Add` > `Existing Project` and then just delete the blank winforms project in the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you *could* just copy the relevant file(s) into the new project, it's better [not to repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY). So either "Add Exiting Item", but **link** the files from their original location...

[image]

...with the following result in solution explorer (note the "shortcut arrows")...

[image]

...or, better yet, extract the relevant subset of functionality into its own project, then just reference that whole project within the new project.

---

OTOH, if you want to use the existing form just as a starting point for further customization, consider...

- encapsulating the original form into a custom control, then placing that control on the new form,
- or [visual form inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on a form (or even on a control from the above).

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just copy the entire solution X in explorer, then open it and delete all the things that you don't want or need.

Comment: will this not cause problems if you wish to rename the solution and projects within it?